# I have a paper in review. Can I send to to NIPS (Neural Information Processing Systems) conference as well?

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science

Question is in the title.  I'm not in computer science but I have a paper that I think is a novel application of machine learning.  It's now in review.

I'm not sure how competitive I'll be, but I think that it's worth sending to NIPS.  Most of the conferences in my field don't publish the papers that comprise them, but NIPS does.  If my paper is published in the NIPS proceedings, would that constitute prior publication?

Does it depend on the journal?  If so, what about the top interdisciplinary journals, like Science/Nature/PNAS?

Answer (score 5):

NIPS does not allow for [dual submissions](https://nips.cc/Conferences/2018/CallForPapers).

> **Dual submissions:** Dual submissions will be identified via a combination of automated methods and human (reviewer, area chair, senior area chair, program chair) judgment. NIPS coordinates with other conferences to identify dual submissions. Submissions that are identical or substantially similar to papers that are in submission to, have been accepted to, or have been published in other archival conferences, journals, workshops, etc. will be deemed dual submissions. Submissions that are identical or substantially similar to other NIPS submissions will also be deemed dual submissions; submissions should be distinct and sufficiently substantial. Note that slicing contributions too thinly may result in submissions being deemed dual submissions. The program chairs reserve the right to reject all NIPS submissions by all authors of dual submissions, not just those deemed dual submissions. The NIPS policy on dual submissions applies for the entire duration of the reviewing process (i.e., from the submission deadline to the notification date). Authors should contact the program chairs if they need further clarification.

There is a good chance that the journal does not either.